# Passing data through views context to javascript in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass some data from the views.py to a template and using it in a javascript and I can't make it work. Does anyone know how can I solve this?

In the views.py

```
listaUsuarios = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
context = {'listaUsuarios':listaUsuarios}

return render(request, redirect, context)
```

This actually works and if I do a `print(listaUsuarios[2])`  it shows just the username number 2 in the database.

The javascript in the template

```
function checkForm(form)
{
 for (i = 0; i < listaUsuarioss.length; i++) {
     if(form.username.value==listaUsuarioss[i]){
 alert("Error: El nombre de usuario ya está en uso");
       form.username.focus();
 return false;
 }
}
}
```

The invocation to the script

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}" onsubmit="return checkForm(this,{‌{listaUsuarios}});">
```

I know I should have used Django forms for the registration but I didn't and I'm trying to make this work for checking before the registration of a new user if that username is already in use.

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: i think first assign the listaUsuarios to a javascript list and then iterate. You have to use special template syntax

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript doesn't have any access to Django template variables. You need to send the list as JSON, parse it in the JS and assign the result to a local variable there.

```
context = {'listaUsuarios': json.dumps(list(listaUsuarios))}
```

...

```
function checkForm(form) {
    var listaUsuarios = JSON.parse({{ listaUsarios|safe }});
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not working yet, could it be because the context is not in the template when the javascript is resolved? I get this error:
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'username'")

Comment: No, and that error can't possibly have anything to do with this code.

Comment: If the javascript worked it should stop the post method and that error wouldn't appear so I guess it's something around the list of usernames.